# Powershell script to apply Caption-Abstract on image from .txt file

Tags: powershell

Question answered!

Feel free to use code below, alter  to correct paths on your system.

```
[Array] $arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path '<path>\renameFileTitle.txt'
$iterator = 0
$files = Get-ChildItem "<path>\*.jpg"
$arrayFromFile[0]
foreach ($file in $files){
    $i = $arrayFromFile[$iterator]
    <path>\exiftool.exe exiftool -Caption-Abstract="$i" $file.FullName
    $iterator++
}
```

Comment: In what way does `$arrayFromFile[i]` "not work as intended"? What exactly seems to be the problem? Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `$i = 0` again in every iteration. Move it outside the loop.

```
# initialization
$i = 0
foreach ($file in $files) {
    C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Pics\exiftool.exe exiftool -Caption-Abstract=$arrayFromFile[$i] $file.FullName
    # increase at every iteration
    $i++
}
```

Comment: You are right. Managed to solve it after a while. Thanks a lot for the help! Adding the finished code if someone ever needs to use exiftool for the same purpose! Check code block, it's been edited.

Comment: @chrisaern Glad I could help. You should not correct the code in your question though, else it would not be clear anymore what your original problem was.